# How to add sheet from one workbook to other workbook using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I am working on a requirement where i have 2 excel, each excel has 1 sheet. and I have to create an other excel which should have both sheets of my input excel using Apache POI.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can only do this by copying cell by cell from one file to the other.

Comment: Yes, i am also trying out something like this only. but no firm results yet.

Comment: the main problem with copying cells is that you have to handle the different cell types (text, number, date, formulas) differently. you will end up with quite some code if you want to do this properly. if you want to copy style and formats as well it gets even worse. :-( I wonder if you have xlsx files if playing around with the XML code is easier at the end of the day.

Comment: The file format i have is .xls i need to only use HSSF as per my requirement.